# Want to get specific value from string

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript string `sentrptg2c#appqueue#sentrptg2c#vwemployees#`.

I want to get last string `vwemployees` through RegExp or from any JavaScript function.

Please suggest a way to do this in JavaScript.

Comment: i have tried some regex to do this but not successful and also tried to convert string in an array to get last element

Comment: Why do you want to use regexp?

Comment: because string will be dynamic every time having new keywords, so i thing regex is correct option for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`split` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var str = "sentrptg2c#appqueue#sentrptg2c#vwemployees#";
str = str.split("#");
str = str[str.length-2];
alert(str);

// Output: vwemployees
```

The reason for `-2` is because of the trailing `#`. If there was no trailing `#`, it would be `-1`.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjeUA/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "...#value#";
var re = /#([^#]+)#^/;
var answer = re.match(s)[1] || null;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're sure the string will be separated by "#" then you can split on # and take the last entry...  I'm stripping off the last #, if it's there, before splitting the string.

```
var initialString = "sentrptg2c#appqueue#sentrptg2c#vwemployees#"
var parts = initialString.replace(/\#$/,"").split("#"); //this produces an array

if(parts.length > 0){
  var result = parts[parts.length-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like [this](http://snipplr.com/view/14074/):

```
String.prototype.between = function(prefix, suffix) {
  s = this;
  var i = s.indexOf(prefix);
  if (i >= 0) {
    s = s.substring(i + prefix.length);
  }
  else {
    return '';
  }
  if (suffix) {
    i = s.indexOf(suffix);
    if (i >= 0) {
      s = s.substring(0, i);
    }
    else {
      return '';
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No magic numbers:

```
var str = "sentrptg2c#appqueue#sentrptg2c#vwemployees#";
var ar = [];
ar = str.split('#');
ar.pop();
var o = ar.pop();
alert(o);
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XYEBD/)